# How to open menu from a button disabling menu key

Tags: java, android, menu

[PRINT SCREEN](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XW2Bu.png)

I'm willing to block to the user the possibility to open the menu using menu key.
The menu must be opened only from the menu button in my application.
So I deleted this part of code:

```
@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
    return true;
}
```

Now if I press the key button it happens nothing and that's what I wanted.
The problem is that if I press my menu button in app, the menu doesn't show up anymore...

So what do?
I thought to add the

```
getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
```

in my listener on the menu button but here is the error and I don't understand what to do... any advice?
Thank you!

Comment: I assume you have this 'menu' variable declared and instanciated in your code. Did you try to add the modifier final on it? Since you are inside an annonymous inner class, the variables you use need to be final.

Comment: ehm.. no I haven't declared/instanciated that menu variable (the one underlined in red)... The problem is that I don't know how to do it, do you know how to??

And my code is placed in OnResume();

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do it with Style templates. If SDK < Jelly Bean use style with ActionBar.

Answer (score 1):

You have to add the onCreateOptionsMenu part. But override the onKeyDown event to disable the menu key. Like this:

```
 @Override
    public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event)
    {
        return keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_MENU || super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure but this should work

Define this variable in your `main class` (outside all subclasses) -

```
public class ... extends ... {

boolean menu = false;
...
}
```

And then whenever you click on `menu button` on your print screen, do the following -

```
@Override
public void onClick(View v){
    menu = true;
    openOptionMenu();
}
```

And in your `onCreateOptionMenu`, do this -

```
@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {

    if(menu){
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
    }
    menu = false;
    return true;

}
```

Comment: already tried buddy but then I can't open the menu from my menu button (there is a imagebutton called menu in my activity where users suppose to open the menu from)...